# FBSDKGraphRequest don't return first_name someties

Tags: facebook-ios-sdk

For some users, FBSDKGraphRequest work, no error, but user["first_name"] is nil.

My code :

```
  class func sessionStateChanged(token: String, viewController: UIViewController) {
// If the session was opened successfully
let request = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "email, first_name, last_name, gender"])
request.startWithCompletionHandler({(connection, user, error) -> Void in
  if (error==nil) {
    let params = [
      "uid": user["id"] as! String,
      "token": token,
      "user": [
        "login": user["email"] as! String,
        "billing_address_attributes": [
          "gender": user["gender"] as! String,
          "first_name": user["first_name"] as! String,
          "last_name": user["last_name"] as! String
        ]
      ]
    ]
  }
})
```

I try with user without authorization, or with limited authorization, I can't reproduce this issue.

I use SDK iOS 4.11.0, with latest FBGraph version,

Answer (score 0):

open this url and check developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer you can check the result from facebook